# I need to parse huge xml array with min 300 elements , but it slow downs , i need advice

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying with this code to parse xml elements of an array. With small amount of elements it works fine,
but when elements are more than 50 , its appears a problem. it slows down very quiclky and even the process get stack.

```
$url=array('{250 domain names}')
foreach($url as $url){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.$url);
    $rank=isset($xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY)?$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes()->TEXT:0;
    $web=(string)$xml->SD[0]->attributes()->HOST;
    echo "$web ---> $rank<br>";
}
```

i need at least 250 domains to put on php array , but output gets stack.
is there some other method of codding so the output appears with no slows?
thanx in advance.

Comment: The problem is down to making multiple web requests, if you can call the API for more than 1 set of data at a time it would help.

Comment: u mean that its better to use curl with function?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use `curl` or `simplexml_load_file`. The problem is doing 250 HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar noted you're doing an excessive amount of http requests back to back. Possibly look into batching curl requests.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php